# VS2015 C# Android app ClientWebSocket timeout at 200 seconds

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, mono, xamarin.android

I'm developing an android app in VS2015 with C# using the ClientWebSocket class. I'm not new to C#, but I am new to android development (for what it's worth). Everything works fine except at about 200 seconds, I get an exception:

> 01-19 15:25:44.137 I/mono-stdout( 1484): Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
>
> > at System.Net.WebConnection.Read (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1038
>
> 01-19 15:25:44.140 I/mono-stdout( 1484): Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
>
> 01-19 15:25:44.146 I/mono-stdout( 1484):   at System.Net.WebConnection.Read (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1038
>
> > at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket+c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 () [0x002e8] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs:280
> >
> > at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680
> >
> > at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
>
> ...

It doesn't matter if I have 1000's of messages flowing or none, once I establich a connection it will throw that exception after about 200 seconds (about 199,870 milliseconds, to be more exact).

Here is my core ClientWebSocket code:

```
public async Task Start(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();

        Task connectTask = webSocket.ConnectAsync(new System.Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
        await connectTask;

        // test code ---------------
        stopwatch.Start();
        // test code ---------------

        Task receiveTask = Receive();
        await receiveTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (webSocket != null)
            webSocket.Dispose();

        // test code ---------------
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time from start to finish : {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        // test code ---------------
        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
        }
    }


public async Task Receive()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
        {
            [business logic handling the message]
        }
    }
}
```

The exception 'happens' from within the Receive loop and gets caught in Start catch.

Some things to note: I am passing JSON text back and forth. As I mentioned, I could have 1000's of messages flowing or none and the time to exception is the same.

I'm assuming I'm bumping up to some timeout, but I don't have a clue what it could be or how to prevent it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please debug to check in which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: I added more of the exception and added more detail. The exception happens specifically at "webSocket.ReceiveAsync".

Comment: Update: I ended up bailing on using the ClientWebSocket class and replaced it with a 3rd party WebSocket library, WebSocket4Net. There seems to be a bug in the ClientWebSocket library class and I don't have the luxury of trying to figure a way around it. Now my app runs with no issue.